# Shift values that satisfy some rule

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array of numbers and wish to remove all the nonpositive (that is, zero or negative) numbers at the start of the array. Here's what I have:

```
shiftlbl:
$shift = shift @ary;
if (0 >= $shift) {goto shiftlbl;}
else {unshift @ary, $shift;}
```

Is there a way that works better (faster), or that works approximately equally well but is more Perlish or easier to read?

Comment: Please show your expected input and output.

Comment: @AruneshSingh, it's in the introductory sentence. (But if you need an example, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32483916 has a good one.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using any module, you can use

```
shift @ary while @ary && $ary[0] <= 0;
```

Not only is it much more readable; it's also much faster.

Or, you can try change the array just once, which could speed up the process if the portion to delete is very long:

```
use List::Util qw{ first };
my $i = first { $ary[$_] > 0 } 0 .. $#ary;
splice @ary, 0, $i;
```

For `-1000 .. 200`, I'm getting

```
         Rate    old    new splice
old    2782/s     --   -62%   -69%
new    7371/s   165%     --   -17%
splice 8886/s   219%    21%     --
```

Here is the whole code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use List::Util qw{ first };
use Test::More;
use Benchmark qw{ cmpthese };


sub old {
    my @ary = @_;
  shiftlbl:
    my $shift = shift @ary;
    if (0 >= $shift) {goto shiftlbl;}
    else {unshift @ary, $shift;}
    return @ary
}


sub new {
    my @ary = @_;
    shift @ary while @ary && $ary[0] <= 0;
    return @ary
}


sub sp {
    my @ary = @_;
    my $i = first { $ary[$_] > 0 } 0 .. $#ary;
    splice @ary, 0, $i;
    return @ary
}

my @ar = (-1000 .. 200);

is_deeply([old(@ar)], [new(@ar)], 'old - new');
is_deeply([old(@ar)], [sp(@ar)], 'old - splice');

cmpthese(-5,
         {
          old    => sub { old(@ar) },
          new    => sub { new(@ar) },
          splice => sub { sp(@ar)  },

          # Also tried with similar results:
          # old    => 'old( -1000 .. 200)',
          # new    => 'new( -1000 .. 200)',
          # splice => 'sp(  -1000 .. 200)',

         });

done_testing();
```

Comment: Thanks, And if you add TSIBN's solution, you'll find it faster than your first, but slower than your second.

Comment: @ikegami When I add `sub lmu { my @ary = @_; @ary = after_incl { $_ > 0 } @ary; return @ary; }` to choroba's benchmark, List::MoreUtils is 46% faster than the `splice` solution and 53% faster than the `while` loop. Did I screw up the benchmark or is something else going on here?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Weird. For me, it's 2 times slower than the old solution :-)

Comment: @choroba Very weird. Even when I use the pure Perl version, I get similar results (which in both cases is roughly 500% faster than the OP's original code). What version of Perl and List::MoreUtils are you using? I wonder if something was tuned significantly in one or the other.

Comment: Perl 5.22.0 on cygwin, Windows 7, L::MU 0.413.

Comment: @choroba Thanks. Using L::MU 0.413 and perl 5.22.0 on Linux, I get a ~330% improvement over `old`, a ~85% improvement over `new`, and a ~25% improvement over `sp`. So it looks like L::MU isn't optimized for Windows, which confirms comments I've gotten about the performance of other L::MU solutions. Thanks again.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: 5.18.1 on Linux: `lmu` still wins, but the differences are smaller: 10, 30 250%.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `after_incl` from [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#after_incl-BLOCK-LIST):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;
use List::MoreUtils qw(after_incl);

my @numbers = (-2, -17, 2, -1, 5, 0);

my @starts_positive = after_incl { $_ > 0 } @numbers;

dd \@starts_positive;
```

#### Output:

```
[2, -1, 5, 0]
```

`after_incl` takes a list, applies a block to it until the block returns true, and returns a list of values from that point to the end of the original list.

Comment: Oh, thank you! (And -- of course. I should have checked that module.)

Comment: @ ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I deleted my comment (before yours was posted) because there was indication that it was wrong, and Benchmark since performed showed it to be wrong. List::MoreUtils and List::MoreUtils::XS is the same code.